# Segmentation falult while reading a character in C

Tags: c, struct

My program compiles successfully. It reads all the integer values but whenever I try to input the character , it gives segmentation fault error. I can't figure out what is the problem. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct soldier
{
    int skill;
    int superior;
};
struct soldier army[1000000];
int n;
int skillSum=0;
void findSkillSum(int);
int main()
{
    int m,parent,child,s,update,i;
    char command;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    // struct soldier army[n+10];
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      scanf("%d",&army[i].skill);
    army[1].superior =0;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&parent,&child);
        army[child].superior = parent;

    }
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
           scanf("%c",&command);
           // s=command[2]-48;
           if(command=='Q')
           {
              scanf("%d",&s);
              findSkillSum(s);
              printf("%d",skillSum);
              printf("\n");

           }
           else
           {
               scanf("%d",&s);
               scanf("%d",&update);
               army[s].skill=update;
           }

     }


}

void findSkillSum(int s)
{
   int i;
   for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if (army[i].superior==s)
        {
            skillSum+=army[i].skill;
            findSkillSum(i);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` looks plenty wrong to me....

Comment: Which line is your debugger indicating the crash occurs on?

Comment: You want to use `scanf(" %c",&command);` (added a space before `%c`) to get the next *non-whitespace* character.

Comment: `findSkillSum` There is a case that recursive call does not stop.

Comment: in addition of SouravGhosh comments, an array of size `n` is defined form `0` to `n-1`, so loop `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` looks wrong. Also, you didn't give us enough details: which line produce error ? what is value you entered for `n`, `m`, `parent`, ` child` you got errors ?

Comment: Thanks Klas Lindback .the code is working fine now. Never new a space should be added before %c to get the next non-whitespace character

Comment: What is your input ?

Answer (score 1):

A space should be added before %c to get the next non-whitespace character

```
 scanf(" %c",&command);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you've already solved the segmentation fault, I'll just give you a tip to understand what causes it.

**GDB:**

If you want to know what is provoking a segmentation fault, you just need to debug your program with [gdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger). That's easy as:

```
gdb -q ./program.out
```

This will start gdb, then just run the program with `run` command, and insert the input. At the moment I inserted a character insted than a number the program stoped with a [SIGSEGV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) fault.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400637 in main () at 1.c:29
29              army[child].superior = parent;
```